# How to undo exec > /dev/null in bash?

Tags: bash

I used

```
exec > /dev/null
```

to suppress output.

Is there a command to undo this? (Without restarting the script.)

Answer (score 25):

To do it right, you need to copy the original FD 1 somewhere else before repointing it to /dev/null. In this case, I store a backup on FD 5:

```
exec 5>&1 >/dev/null
...
exec 1>&5
```

Another option is to redirect stdout within a block rather than using `exec`:

```
{
    ...
} >/dev/null
```

Comment: "exec >&5 >/dev/null" will answer with "bash: 5: Bad file descriptor".

Comment: @user2267134 Oops. Fixed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Is there a way to redirect both STDERR and STDOUT using the first method? Currently, it only redirects STDOUT (&1).

Comment: @jerzy, of course; you can simply copy the new stdout to stderr, by putting `2>&1` *after* each place where stdout has been successfully redirected (redirections are processed left-to-right).

Comment: @jerzy, ...that said, you might want to back up stderr separately (ie. to FD 6) instead; otherwise, on restoring it, you'd be forcing it to be identical to stdout, even if it wasn't identical to begin with. In that case, you'd add a `6>&2` on the backup side, and a `2>&6` on the restore side.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy!

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to get output again at the command prompt, you can do this:

```
exec >/dev/tty
```

If you are creating a script, and you want to have the output of a certain group of commands redirected, put those commands in braces:

```
{
   command
   command
} >/dev/null
```

Comment: This is only correct if the original stdout went to the TTY, which may or may not be the case.

Comment: @charlesduffy: OK.  Maybe I missed the point.  I  thought they were just trying to see output again at a command prompt.

Comment: Good point about redirecting code blocks. Hope you don't mind if I adopt it.

Answer (score 2):

Save the original output targets beforehand.

```sh
# $$ = the PID of the running script instance
STDOUT=`readlink -f /proc/$$/fd/1`
STDERR=`readlink -f /proc/$$/fd/2`
```

And restore them again using `exec`.

```sh
exec 1>$STDOUT 2>$STDERR
```

If you use `/dev/tty` for restoration as in the answers above, contrary to this, you won't be able to do redirections in call-level, e.g. `bash script.sh &>/dev/null` won't work.

Comment: This is very Linux-only, whereas many of the other solutions given will work on Unix-y systems that don't have `/proc/*/fd` (of which MacOS is a widespread/mainstream example).

Answer (score -1):

Not really, as that would require changing the state of a running process. Even assuming you could, whatever you wrote before resetting standard output is truly, completely gone, as it was sent to the bit bucket.

Answer (score -1):

To restore stdout I use

```
unset &1
```

Comment: Eh? Bash appears to implement this as `unset & 1` -- which is to say, running `unset` in the background, followed by running `1` as a command. Moreover, looking at its file descriptor table after a redirection, I don't see any evidence that it kept a backup, and thus that any restore operation is possible. Are you sure you didn't get this syntax from a different shell?