# How to undo exec 2> /dev/null in bash?

Tags: bash

I used

```
exec 2> /dev/null
```

to suppress output.

Is there a command to undo this? (Without restarting the script.)

Question analogue to [How to undo exec > /dev/null in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840322/how-to-undo-exec-dev-null-in-bash)

Comment: Here is your answer:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840322/how-to-undo-exec-dev-null-in-bash][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840322/how-to-undo-exec-dev-null-in-bash

Comment: Since you figured out that the question was analogous, couldn't you see that the answer would also be analogous?

Comment: No it was non-obvious to me. Needed 10 minutes or so to figure out. It shouldn't happen again for me or anyone else, so I decided to add it.

Answer (score 2):

To do it right, you need to copy the original FD 2 somewhere else before repointing it to /dev/null. In this case, I store a backup on FD 6:

```
exec 6>&2 2>/dev/null
...
exec 2>&6
```

Credit for this answer goes to [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy), who answered a very similar question: [How to undo exec > /dev/null in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17840518/2610886)

Comment: It's good that you provide the reference, but you shouldn't copy/paste someone else's answer and claim it as your own.

Comment: Sorry! I thought "Answer analogue to http://stackoverflow.com/a/17840518/2610886" will make that clear. Added proper credit. Feel free to add to reputation to him, if that's possible. I just wanted to add it this for completeness and in case I need it myself again.

Comment: no worries. I know what you meant to do, but it's easy to misinterpret. The proper thing to do is to block quote the other answer, like this: An analogous answer is [LINK]: QUOTE