# Can I only show stdout/stderr in case of a trapped error in bash?

Tags: bash

How I wish it to work:

- When no errors are bash trapped (if nothing returns a non-zero exit code [unless overwritten by || true]), be silent. Hide stdout and stderr.
- When an error is bash trapped, be verbose. Write stdout and stderr.

In my script only stdout and stderr is missing.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 5>&1 >/dev/null
exec 6>&2 2>/dev/null

error_handler() {
   local return_code="$?"
   local last_err="$BASH_COMMAND"

   local stdout= # How to read FD 5?

   local stderr= # How to read FD 6?

   exec 1>&5
   exec 2>&6

   echo "ERROR!   
scriptname: $0
BASH_COMMAND: $last_err
\$?: $return_code
stdout: $stdout
stderr: $stderr
" 1>&2

   exit 1
} 

trap "error_handler" ERR

echo "Some message..."

# Some command fails, i.e. return a non-zero exit code.

mkdir
```

I could probably redirect stdout/stderr to a temporary file and use cat to show it in case an error was bash trapped. Would be a bit better, if that temporary file wasn't required. Any idea?

Credit:
This question was inspired by question [How to undo exec > /dev/null in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840322/how-to-undo-exec-dev-null-in-bash) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17840518/2610886) by [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the I/O redirection carefully:

```
exec 5>&1  >/dev/null
exec 6>&2 2>/dev/null
```

We see that file descriptor 5 is a duplicate of the original standard output, but that standard output is going to `/dev/null`.  Similarly, 6 is a duplicate of standard error, but standard error is going to `/dev/null`.

Now let's consider what happens when you run:

```
ls -l /dev/null /dev/not-actually/there
```

The `ls` command writes the output for `/dev/null` to `/dev/null` because that's where its standard output is directed.  Similarly, it writes the error for the non-existent file `/dev/not-actually/there` to `/dev/null` because that's where its standard error is directed.

Thus, both the standard output and standard error of the command are irrevocably lost.

Given the expressed requirements, there isn't going to be a simple solution.  Your best bet is probably to redirect both standard output and standard error to the same file (but be aware that the interleaving of error and normal output may be different because the output is a file).  Alternatively, you can direct standard output and standard error to two separate files and show them when necessary.

Note that you will need to consider emptying the output file(s) after each command (letting the `trap` report the contents before the file(s) is/are emptied) so that you don't report the standard output or standard error of commands 1-9 when command 10 fails.

Doing this neatly and handling pipelines correctly, etc, is not trivial.  I'm not sure whether to suggest a function that's passed the command and arguments (tricky for pipelines) or some other technique.

I've used the 'capture everything in one file' technique in `cron`-run scripts that mail the output when appropriate.  It isn't wholly satisfactory, but it is a lot better than not having the error messages at all.

You can consider playing with `expect` and/or pseudo-ttys, but doing a good job will be really hard.

Comment: Except for pipes, redirection is processed left to right.  Thus you end up with 5 going to the original stdout before it was redirected to `/dev/null`, same thing for 6 and stderr.  `( exec 5>&1 >/dev/null; echo hello; echo >&5 goodbye )` outputs "goodbye".  So that much of the OP script is correct.  There's just no way to read what's sent to stdout/stderr if you don't redirect them to a file.

Answer (score 2):

Your file descriptors 5 and 6 are write-only.  There's no way for the shell to read its own output; bidirectional pipes are deadlocks waiting to happen even when it's not the same process on both ends.

I would go with the temp file idea.

Answer (score 0):

The actual paths to I/O files are hidden from the shells, and other applications; you need a program that knows how to dig for the details. **lsof** may come to your rescue, if your system supports it. Try adding the following in your error routine:

```
local name0="$(basename "$0")";
lsof -p$$ -d5,6 2>/dev/null |
    egrep "^${name0:0:5}[^ ]* +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[56][a-zA-Z]* "
```

This will require some tweaking to get it to be robust (short program names, program names with spaces in them, ...), and more friendly (stdout for "4" and "stderr for "3"... say replacing the program name in column 1). But when you tweak beware the huge variations in output formats you may encounter. Not just between systems but between different file types on the same system. I leave this as an exercise for the student.