# View output of process redirected to dev/null - undo redirection

Tags: linux, shell, io-redirection

I've pushed a couple of process to background and redirected the output to `/dev/null`. I want undo that and see what's happening since its been in the background for a long time.

Is there a way to undo the `> /dev/null` redirection and bring the process to foreground?

Comment: _After the program is already started_ it's harder to fix unless you're modifying that program's source code to explicitly add the feature, but you can always use a tool like sysdig or (with a much, much larger performance penalty) strace to interactively watch what's being written to `/dev/null`; sysdig in particular has a "chisel" (a helper script written in lua) that reassembles content into something that looks a lot like tailing the stdout would.

Comment: Insofar as this is about interactive use and not about writing a script that can undo a redirection partway through, I'd argue that it belongs on [unix.se]. (The on-topic variant is asked-and-answered here as, f/e, [How to undo `exec >/dev/null` in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840322/how-to-undo-exec-dev-null-in-bash))

Answer (score 1):

I think you question would be better posted on [unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

There, you can find [How to change the output redirection of a running process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/59157/164309), which exactly your question casted in a more general form.

From the answers, and from the 3rd party tool ([`redirect`](https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/reredirect/)) suggested in the accepted answer by its creator, which is mostly written in C, I deduce that there's no shell-only way to accomplish what you want.

However that question is from 2012, so you might want to ask a new one to see if something changed in the meanwhile.

Last but not least, doing some search in `man bash` I've found the `Coprocesses` section, that reads

> ```
> […] A coprocess is executed asynchronously in a subshell, as if the command had been
> terminated with the & control operator, with a two-way pipe established between
> the executing shell and the coprocess. […] The standard output of command is
> connected via a pipe to a file descriptor in the executing shell, and that
> file descriptor is assigned to NAME[0]. The standard input […]
> ```

which is probably a way to launch processes in background without losing the ability to change their file descriptors, if I interpret the quote correctly.

Comment: Using coprocesses doesn't really buy you anything you wouldn't also get by having stdin and stdout connected to named FIFOs. I'm not convinced that it's a meaningful solution to the OP's problem here.

Comment: ...after all, if someone knew ahead-of-time they wanted to do this, they could also pipe to something like `while IFS= read -r line; if (( trash )); then :; else printf '%s\n'; fi; done` with a trap set to accept a signal on SIGUSR1 and such and toggle whether `trash` is true. Lots of solutions, but the thing that makes this question distinct from the preexisting on-topic ones is that they're trying to fix a mistake they made when they _didn't_ set things up ahead-of-time knowing they'd change their mind about where to send the output later.