# Can I stop 'tee' temporarily in a shell script?

Tags: bash, tee

bash 4.2 centos7

---

test.sh

```
LOG_FILE=./logs/result.log

exec > >(tee -a ${LOG_FILE} )
exec 2> >(tee -a ${LOG_FILE} >&2)
echo

for x in {1..3}
do
  echo $x
done


# I want the second part to be displayed but not logged.
for x in {4..6}
do
  echo $x
done


# Recommence logging
for x in {7..9}
do
  echo $x
done
```

---

**desired output**

console

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

result.log

```
1
2
3
7
8
9
```

---

**question**

Can I stop or revert the redirection of  `exec > >(tee -a ${LOG_FILE} )` inside the same shell?
Or should I use different method than `tee`?

---

EDIT2

I'm struggling to get this function out of the log.

```
spinner()
{
  trap "kill 0" SIGINT
  spin='-\|/'
  i=0
  while kill -0 $1 2>/dev/null
  do
    i=$(( (i+1) %4 ))
    printf "\e[1;33m" >&3
    printf "\r${spin:$i:1}" >&3
    printf "\e[m" >&3
    sleep .1
  done
}
```

I put `>&3` in three `printf` lines but it results in `Bad file descriptor`. The function gets a pid parameter and spins the wheel until the delivered pid is done.

Comment: This is _very_ closely related to [How to undo `exec >/dev/null` in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840322/how-to-undo-exec-dev-null-in-bash) -- it's essentially the exact same question, with the only difference being where the redirection you want to undo targets.

Comment: Also, note that `exec >(tee stdout) 2>(tee stderr >&2)` can be written all on one line; and that whether or not you do so, redirecting both stdout and stderr through tee means you lose ordering guarantees.

Comment: (What I mean by "lose ordering guarantees" is that if your program is writing `O`s to stdout and `E`s to stderr, `OEOE` can change to `OOEE` or `EEOO` or any other combination; the writes to either of the two specific copies of tee will stay in order, but it's not guaranteed that they'll come out on the console in the original order relative to lines written to the other stream).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes I'm experiencing the exact problem you mentioned. Will `exec >(tee stdout) 2>&1` work better?

Comment: Yes, it will. (_sigh_ re: minimum comment length limit)

Comment: Although `exec > >(tee stdout) 2>&1` will work better, it still doesn't enforce the ordering of standard output and standard error because the standard error is not fully buffered but standard output usually is.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, it makes the behavior as good as you'd get with running your script `>file 2>&1` or `2>&1 | less`, and that's generally good enough -- if the program's output is unhelpful to users when run that way, its maintainers are reasonably likely to hear about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save a copy of the original standard output so that you can send the middle section to it once more, like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

LOG_DIR="./logs"
LOG_FILE="$LOG_DIR/result.log"

mkdir -p "$LOG_DIR"

exec 3>&1   # Save a copy of standard output as file descriptor 3

exec > >(tee -a ${LOG_FILE} )
exec 2> >(tee -a ${LOG_FILE} >&2)
echo

for x in {1..3}
do
  echo $x
done

# I want the second part to be displayed but not logged.
{
for x in {4..6}
do
  echo $x
done
} 1>&3

# Recommence logging
for x in {7..9}
do
  echo $x
done
```

There are multiple ways of restoring the middle section to write just to the original standard output, but I think the `{ … } 1>&3` notation is probably the simplest.

Beware: you have two copies of `tee` both writing to the same file.  If you're lucky (careful), the one processing standard error won't have anything to write to the log file.  You might be better off using `2>&1` like this `exec > >(tee …) 2>&1` and omitting the `exec 2> >(tee …)` line. Also, note that the prompt may appear before the last of the logging output.

```
$ bash script.sh
4
5
6
$
1
2
3
7
8
9
echo Hi
Hi
$
```

I typed the `echo Hi` to the prompt `$` on the line after the `6`.

The file `logs/result.log` contained one copy of the sequence "blank line, numbers 1-3, numbers 7-9" for each time I tested the script.

See also the Bash manual on:

- [I/O Redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections)
- [Duplicating file descriptors](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Duplicating-File-Descriptors)
- [Command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping) for an explanation of `{ … }`.

Comment: will the `1>&3` part work on the end of a function? Will `test(){echo hi} 1>&3` work everytime it is called?

Comment: @Lunartist, it'd be safer and clearer to make it `test() { { echo hi; echo bye; } >&3; }` (assuming your real function will have multiple commands you want to redirect, not just the one echo -- otherwise it'd make more sense to just put the redirection right on the echo).

Comment: No, but `test() { echo hi 1>&3; }` should work.  I believe the semicolon is necessary — it certainly is in most shells (so you should have written `test() { echo  Hi; } 1>&3` where many of the spaces are optional).

Comment: I'm having a `Bad file descriptor` errors. Edited the post for detail.

Comment: @Lunartist, that'd be normal if the `exec 3>&1` hadn't happened earlier (and to be effective, it needs to be _before_ the `exec >(tee ...)`). I don't see anywhere in your edited question that says you followed that part of the answer.

Comment: managed the bad FD problem. Could I ask one last question? Do you have any suggestion regarding the display order? (unintentionally showing `1>&3>&1` first before `tee` displays `1`)

Comment: That's really worth it's own question. I've managed that kind of thing in the past by actually shutting down the tee and waiting for it to flush (trying to grab an advisory lock that it was caused to inherit, so it truly exited before the next command is run), but the technique is way too intricate to show in a comment.