# On what occasion does 'tee' deletes the file it was writing on?

Tags: bash, tee

bash4.2, centos

---

the script

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILE=$homedir/logs/result.log
exec 3>&1
exec > >(tee -a ${LOG_FILE}) 2>&1
echo
    
end_shell_number=10

for script in `seq -f "%02g_*.sh" 0 $end_shell_number`; do
    if ! bash $homedir/$script; then
        printf 'Script "%s" failed, terminating...\n' "$script" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

It basically runs through sub-shells number 00 to 10 and logs everything to a `LOG_FILE` while also displaying on stdout.

I was watching the log getting stacked with `tail -F ./logs/result.log`,
and it was working nicely until the log file suddenly got removed.

The sub-shells does nothing related to file descriptors nor the log file. They remotely restart tomcats via `ssh` commands.

---

Question :
`tee` was writing on a log file successfully until the file gets erased and logging stops from then on.
Is there a filesize limit or timeout in `tee`? Is there any known behavior of `tee` that it deletes a file?

Comment: Note, that you are asking specifically solely about  tee, not your actual problem. Is it XY question?

Comment: Do you have more than one `tee` writing to the same file (as you did in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68659607/can-i-stop-tee-temporarily-in-a-shell-script))?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I removed that logic and only use `exec > >(tee -a ${LOG_FILE}) 2>&1`

Comment: Aside from the correct answer by KamilCuk, I would not redirect stderr. If there is any problem with writing it to the output file, you won't get any hint what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On what occasion does 'tee' deletes the file it was writing on?

`tee` does not delete nor truncate the file once it has started writing.

> Is there a filesize limit or timeout in tee?

No.

> Is there any known behavior of tee that it deletes a file?

No.

Note that file can be removed, but the process (`tee`) still will wrote the open file descriptor, but the file will not be accessible (see `man 3 unlink`).