# Automatically print command output from a separate file

Tags: linux, bash

Is it possible to have the output of commands `separate_file.sh` be visible to the caller of `caller.sh` automatically with the following setup?

I'm aware of adding `>&2` to each of the commands in `separate_file.sh`, but I'm looking for a more automatic solution.

I'm also aware that the output is visible if I call `separate_file.sh` like so: `separate_file.sh` instead of `$(separate_file.sh)`, but I'd like to preserve the `-e` option in `caller.sh` (it's used for other calls).

`caller.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
if [[ ! $(separate_file.sh) ]]; then
    echo 'separate_file.sh failed'
fi
```

`separate_file.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo '1'

ls -la
```

Comment: `exec >&2` will redirect _all future commands'_ stdout to stderr; is that "more automatic" than adding `>&2` after each command?

Comment: ...btw, `set -e` is [not a good idea](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises); assuming good practices are otherwise being used, it makes your code _less_ reliable, not more. ("Good practices" means things like `|| return`, `|| exit`, etc. after each command where a nonzero exit status is intended to cause the given action; if you read the link, you'll see why `set -e` isn't sufficient to reliably cause that effect, and also why the effect is often unwanted).

Comment: BTW, you can run `separate.sh || echo "separate.sh failed"` to let `separate.sh` use exit status to indicate success or failure without `set -e` triggering in either circumstance.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `exec >&2` does sound like it would work. How do I revert it?

Comment: We have other Q&A describing that.  See f/e [How to undo `exec >/dev/null` in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840322/how-to-undo-exec-dev-null-in-bash)